# Additional Managed Metadata Service

Tags: managed-metadata, service-application

I am deploying a small farm and am going to be using a taxonomy. Should I create a new Managed Metadata service application instance or just use the default? What are the advantages/disadvantages?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any advantage or disadvantage of using the default one created by the wizard vs. one you create.  You will have all the same functionality.

Answer (score 1):

A new one should be created if you want certain web apps to have their own set of service apps. By grouping service apps you can allow for instance a web app to use the metadata service app and search but not the BCS by creating a new metadata and search service app and putting them in a new group and then assign the web app to that group.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new Group and term sets in the existing itself and work it out.. as everything remains the same.